# Cassandra Active-Passive Setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, disaster-recovery

Is there a way to setup a `active-passive` mode in `cassandra` 3.11.* at a DC level or Cluster level? Currently active-active DCs are being hosted in a single cluster over a single AWS region across 3 AZs. Is it possible to build a passive DC or a passive Cluster in a multi region setup?

Comment: The client configuration allows for a lot of the things you're asking. You can specify local and remote DCs when you connect, you also have control over the contact points in your connection, and lastly you also have the ability during connection and at the statement level to configure your consistency level - choosing LOCAL_XXXX should keep activity "out" of other DCs (e.g. LOCAL_QUORUM). Hope that helps.

Comment: How do you suggest we replicate the data in active-passive situation?

Comment: Not sure how many nodes you have in each DC, but I would say you would want at least a quorum level on each DC. Up to you though.